# Automatically close non-responsive app

Tags: macos

How can I automatically close an application that is listed as `Not Responding` in Activity Monitor?

I have one application in particular that I'd like to be killed if it goes non-responsive. I'm thinking I could schedule a script with cron, but I'm not sure what the script would need to be.

macOS 10.7

Comment: Really, if you've got an app that's frequently becoming non-responsive, then you want to fix the problem rather than covering over it. However: are you really on OS X Lion? I would recommend moving up to Mountain Lion, at least, which has lots of bug fixes on Lion. Newer OS versions (and the contemporary updates for the apps) may improve matters.

Comment: Also: apps can recover from "Not Responding" states. They may just be busy for a minute or so.

Comment: Echoing benwiggy—as someone on a similarly old version of OS X (Mavericks), Lion is not the place to hang out. Go up to Mountain Lion or Mavericks, or even down one to Snow Leopard.

Comment: @benwiggy The problem is with the app and non-related to the OS: it happens to the same app on other versions of macOS just as frequently. The app is going non-reponsive for multiple days at a time and has not shown signs of recovering. There are no later versions of the app than the one that I'm running and there are no alternative applications to suit; the manufacturer of some hardware I need to run made their own app.

Answer (score -3):

Tap on the Stop button in the upper-left side of the Activity Monitor window (or use the Touch Bar). Select one of the following options: Quit: This is the same as choosing File > Quit within an app. The process quits when it's safe to do so.

Comment: Does this work for "not responding" applications?

Comment: Does this work automatically? It sounds like a manual process.